# How to strip varnish off wood cabinets?

Tags: wood, cabinetry, varnish

[Link to imgur album with pictures](https://imgur.com/a/G2WfXfM)
[image]
So my wife and I recently bought a nice starter home and now we are planning to remodel parts of the house. We are interviewing a few General Contractors to explain what we want and find out whats possible. Though I still want to attempt somethings on my own.

One of the things I want to do on my own is strip and paint the cabinets.

Removing the cabinet doors to strip the varnish shouldn't be too hard (I think) but I want to know about the portions in red boxes (see link above), the parts of the cabinets mounted into the walls. What can I do to strip the varnish from the wall mounted portions of my cabinets.

I am not even sure what to google to find a satisfying answer for my question. What would I call those portions?

And if the answer is honestly. "Dude just buy new cabinets and have them installed, thats fine as well.

I may post this to the reddit home improvement subreddit as well.

Thank you guys again I do appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I have some very good news for you, since you're looking to paint you don't need to strip them at all, *greatly* simplifying things and saving you an unbelievable amount of time and effort. See [Good methods for scuffing/sanding ready-built furniture with contours for repainting](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13069/good-methods-for-scuffing-sanding-ready-built-furniture-with-contours-for-repain) to get you started.

Comment: For future reference if you come back to us with further questions (and please feel free to do so), the SE model is for both Questions and Answers to try to stand alone and not rely exclusively on external links for info or images, since links can go stale at any point in the future and this hugely reduces the future usefulness of the Q&A for future searchers with a similar/the same problem. So upload any photos into the body of the Q, thanks, and if it's info at least précis it here (although a full quote of a relevant section is perfectly acceptable and doesn't violate copyright)

Comment: OP, are you still monitoring this? If you did ask on Reddit, I'd appreciate if you could let us know what (if any) consensus there was there before you subsequently delete this Q, thanks!